# The expression "your right" when used to respond to an apology

Tags: expressions, idiom-request, australian-english

Here in Australia, people say something like 'you're right' or 'your right' or 'you right', sometimes followed by 'mate' to respond to an apology.

Below is an example circumstance:

- Ouch!
- Oops, sorry I stepped on your foot.
- Your right mate

I tried doing some research, but couldn't find any examples.
What does it actually mean?

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing it's properly spelled as **you're right**, and it's just a shortened form of _you're **al**right_, which is an idiomatic way of saying, "No problem; don't worry about it."

Comment: Would it be a shortened form of *"you are all right"*. After some letters are removed and add the apostrophes added, should it be written as *"you're 'right"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is related to the Australian expression "She'll be right", which means that whatever is wrong now will be right (or all right) in time.

The expression "She's right" means that the wrong is already right.

So perhaps the expression "You're right" means that the wrong done ***to you*** is already right -- or is not considered to be a wrong in the first place. This fits in well with the example given.

The word "mate" is a common -- usually male -- bonding word in Australia, making the apology more a peer-to-peer transaction, and more likely to be accepted.